# What are the benefits of using the 'official' temp directory for the OS?

Tags: node.js

I've noticed packages like [node-temp](https://github.com/bruce/node-temp) and [node-tmp](https://github.com/raszi/node-tmp), which provide APIs for writing temporary files to the appropriate temp directory for the current OS, e.g. `/tmp`.

What are the benefits of doing this, compared with simply storing temporary files in a subdirectory of your module/application (e.g. `./temp`)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is certainly operating system specific.

On most Linux systems `/tmp` is a [tmpfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) file system, which works much faster (because all data stays nearly in RAM) than a conventional disk file system.

Also, the official `/tmp/` file system is often a [setuid directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#setuid_and_setgid_on_directories). This impacts on who has the permission to delete files inside it.

And some systems are administrated specially and might have periodic [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) jobs to clean that `/tmp`. Also, system administrators know about `/tmp/` (and might avoid making backups of it, put it on a fast disk, if not on *tmpfs*  etc...) .... And the [Linux Standard Base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base) requires it...

You could use also the [TMPDIR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TMPDIR) environment variable.